# How can I force flash fullscreen to a particular display in a multi-display setup

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to get several Flash animations to come up on different displays at start up. Is there a way in Actionscript that I can force the movie to go fullscreen on a particular display?

Comment: Are you using AIR, or a projector, or just a web browser to play your swf?

Comment: I am using projectors for the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package your flash animations into AIR applications - you can then set the x,y of each application within the properties box / xml.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player chooses which monitor to full-screen to. If there is a solution, it is not AS3.

"Flash Player and AIR use a metric to determine which monitor contains the greatest portion of the SWF, and uses that monitor for full-screen mode."